# glDrawElements doesn't draw when vertices are in for loop

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a circle using vertex arrays, I'm filling the array in a for loop with the points, but nothing is rendered, instead, If I put the values manually in the array everything works fine, I don't know what must be wrong.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h> 

#define PI 3.14159265358979324

static float R = 40.0; // Radius of circle.
static float X = 50.0; // X-coordinate of center of circle.
static float Y = 50.0; // Y-coordinate of center of circle.
static int numVertices = 5; // Number of vertices on circle.

static float vertices[15] =
{

};

static unsigned int stripIndices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
    float t = 0; // Angle parameter.
    int i;


    int k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        vertices[k] = X + R * cos(t);
        k++;
        vertices[k] = Y + R * sin(t);
        k++;
        vertices[k] = 0.0;

        k++;
        t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
    }



    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, stripIndices);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: When do you load data into a VAO?

Comment: How are your source files structured?  Is the snippet above in a `.cpp` file or a `.h`/`.hpp` file?  Is this code in the same file as `main()`?  I suspect it may be an issue with the way you are using the `static` keyword, but it's impossible to tell with the information provided.

Comment: @0x5453 full code is here https://ideone.com/ml6zSS

Comment: Maybe your loop is winding the vertices the wrong way? If this is the problem then `t -= 2 * PI / numVertices;` should fix it.

Comment: You should check your stuff in Renderdoc. I can't help any more because you're using stuff that has been deprecated for probably over a decade. You should instead be learning [modern OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/).

Comment: Given that it works when you initialize vertices manually, what happens if you move the initialization loop into the beginning of the  'setup' function?

Comment: @J.R. Nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, just noticed that you do 'k=1'. That should be 'k=0'.